# More than 2 result sets in stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have followed the guidance for returning more than 1 resultset in a stored procedure with Entity Framework. Found here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
- http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/30738a7c-5176-4333-aa83-98eab8548da5.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675933/Returning-Multiple-Result-Sets-from-an-Entity-Fram?msg=5026933#xx5026933xx

However if a 3rd resultset is returned, after the client code calls the `GetNextResult<T>` there is an error:

> The type parameter 'db.GetShippingItems' in ExecuteFunction is incompatible with the type 'db.GetProductDetails' returned by the function.

`GetProductDetails` is the 2nd return type. The first is `GetProduct`. I added a 3rd ResultMapping to the `FunctionImportMapping` element in the `.edmx` file.

The `FunctionImport` is as follows:

```
<FunctionImport Name="GetProduct">
   <ReturnType Type="Collection(db.GetProduct)" />
   <ReturnType Type="Collection(db.GetProductDetails)" />
   <ReturnType Type="Collection(db.GetProductShippingItems)" />
   <Parameter Name="ProgId" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
</FunctionImport>
```

Comment: magister, have you found a solution to this problem? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: no I just wrote 2 stored procedures each with 2 resultsets inside.  I didn't have any more time to spend on it.

Answer (score 1):

To get third resultset you need to use the GetNextResults() for the second resultset etc.

```
//Get second result set
var products = results.GetNextResult<Product_SprocResult>();
categProd.Products.AddRange(products);

//Get third result set
var statuTypes = products.GetNextResult<StatusType_SprocResult>();                
categProd.StatusTypes.AddRange(statuTypes);
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675933/Returning-Multiple-Result-Sets-from-an-Entity-Fram?msg=5034933#xx5034933xx

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Comment: I didn't try var but I did cast to the Complex_ResultType of the 3rd set.  This was awhile ago.  I will have to dig back into that part of the program.